# Facebook Message Webhook Event : How to identify that the message is a reply/comment of a Page Story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have a bot running well receiving messages through the Facebook message webhook event. Everything works well when the user sends messages through the messenger app.
But When a user replies to the page story, it generates an incoming message as if it was a standard one and it's not possible to handle this context which is completely different form a user initiated conversation.
Any idea how to receive to differentiate a "standard" message from a "reply to page story" one ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to differentiate between these two entry points/sources. Both will trigger a regular message event with no specific attributes added that would allow you to differentiate the source/entry point.